# Duplicate object names in the same package, please rename one

Tags: metadata, notification, package.xml

Trying to retrieve metadata from my developer Org and am getting the below Warning. Any idea how I can resolve this?

> Duplicate object names in the same package,
> 'apexEmailNotifications/apexEmailNotifications.notifications'; please
> rename one Duplicate object names in the same package,
> 'notificationTypeConfig/NotificationTypeConfig.config'; please rename
> one

```
//package.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>ActionLinkGroupTemplate</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>AnimationRule</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>ApexClass</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>ApexComponent</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>ApexEmailNotifications</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>ApexPage</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>ApexTestSuite</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>ApexTrigger</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>AppMenu</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>AppointmentSchedulingPolicy</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>ApprovalProcess</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>AssignmentRule</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>AssignmentRules</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>AuraDefinitionBundle</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>AuthProvider</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>AutoResponseRule</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>AutoResponseRules</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>BrandingSet</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>CallCenter</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>Certificate</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>ChannelLayout</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>ChatterExtension</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>CleanDataService</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>Community</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>CompactLayout</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>ConnectedApp</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>ContentAsset</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>CorsWhitelistOrigin</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>CspTrustedSite</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>CustomApplication</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>CustomApplicationComponent</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>CustomFeedFilter</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>CustomField</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>CustomHelpMenuSection</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>CustomLabels</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>CustomMetadata</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>CustomObject</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>CustomObjectTranslation</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>CustomPageWebLink</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>CustomPermission</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>CustomSite</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>CustomTab</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>Dashboard</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>DataCategoryGroup</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>DelegateGroup</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>DuplicateRule</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>EclairGeoData</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>EscalationRule</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>EscalationRules</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>ExternalDataSource</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>ExternalServiceRegistration</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>FieldSet</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>FlexiPage</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>Flow</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>FlowCategory</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>FlowDefinition</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>GlobalValueSet</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>GlobalValueSetTranslation</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>Group</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>HomePageComponent</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>HomePageLayout</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>IframeWhiteListUrlSettings</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>InstalledPackage</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>Layout</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>LightningBolt</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>LightningComponentBundle</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>LightningExperienceTheme</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>LightningMessageChannel</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>ListView</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>LiveChatSensitiveDataRule</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>ManagedContentType</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>MatchingRule</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>MatchingRules</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>MyDomainDiscoverableLogin</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>NamedCredential</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>NetworkBranding</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>NotificationTypeConfig</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>OauthCustomScope</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>PathAssistant</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>PaymentGatewayProvider</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>PermissionSet</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>PlatformCachePartition</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>PlatformEventChannel</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>PlatformEventChannelMember</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>PostTemplate</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>Profile</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>ProfilePasswordPolicy</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>ProfileSessionSetting</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>Prompt</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>Queue</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>QuickAction</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>RecommendationStrategy</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>RecordActionDeployment</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>RecordType</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>RedirectWhitelistUrl</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>RemoteSiteSetting</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>Report</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>ReportType</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>Role</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>SamlSsoConfig</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>Scontrol</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>Settings</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>SharingRules</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>SharingSet</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>SiteDotCom</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>Skill</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>StandardValueSetTranslation</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>StaticResource</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>SynonymDictionary</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>TopicsForObjects</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>TransactionSecurityPolicy</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>WebLink</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>Workflow</name>
    </types>
    <version>52.0</version>
</Package>
```

Comment: Would you post your package.xml here?

Comment: Added to the question.

Comment: try removing the block of ApexEmailNotifications

Comment: @jonny-harte Did you find a solution to this problem?

Comment: no sorry I think I just ended up removing them from the manifest

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution for this. Had a similar problem myself today, and this was the only thing that showed up when I googled the error. In my case, I was getting this error when I tried to retrieve my LWC and it kept giving me old code. The code had clearly been replaced in the org, since my changes were showing when the LWC was rendered, but whenever I would "retrieved source from org," my changes were somehow not there, and it was accompanied by the aforementioned error.

The solution was to rename the files in the LWC bundle and push them to the org.

Before:

> exampleLwc
>
> - exampleLwc.js
> - exampleLwc.html
> - exampleLwc.js-meta.xml

After:

> exampleLwc
>
> - exampleLwc1.js
> - exampleLwc1.html
> - exampleLwc1.js-meta.xml

Then I pushed the changes to the org, and retrieved them to make sure my changes had taken effect.

After retrieval:

> exampleLwc
>
> - exampleLwc.js
> - exampleLwc.html
> - exampleLwc1.js
> - exampleLwc1.html
> - exampleLwc1.js-meta.xml

After this, I was able to deploy a backup of the component, which solved the issue, and further retrievals showed the following:

> exampleLwc
>
> - exampleLwc.js
> - exampleLwc.html
> - exampleLwc.js-meta.xml